# Error al intentar Filtrar por fechas procedimiento almacenado JAVA MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, date, stored-procedure

Estoy realizando mi método de filtrar por fechas los datos de MYSQL en mi JTable en JAVA, ya realice la codificacion pero tengo un problema, a la hora de darle al filtrar despues de seleccionar las fechas en los dateChooser,me aparece este error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
```

Adjunto mi código del action performed del botón:

```
private void botonFiltrarFechaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    
    Polizas ps = new Polizas();
    
    java.util.Date utilStartDate = fechaInicialD.getDate();
    java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());
    
    java.util.Date utilFinalDate = fechaFinalD.getDate();
    java.sql.Date finalDate = new java.sql.Date(utilFinalDate.getTime());
    
    ps.Fecha=startDate;
    ps.Fecha2=finalDate;
    
    Control control = new Control();
    try {
        control.filtrarPorFechas(startDate, finalDate);
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        
        Logger.getLogger(FrmGenerar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        
        Logger.getLogger(FrmGenerar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        
    }
```

Y mi codigo de filtrarPorFechas:

```
public void filtrarPorFechas(Date startDate, Date finalDate) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    
    Statement sql = Conexion.getConexion().createStatement();
    String consulta = "SELECT * FROM ptjs_accounted WHERE fecha between '?' and '?'";

    PreparedStatement filter = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta);
    
    filter.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
    filter.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(finalDate.getTime()));
    filter.execute();
    
    ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery(consulta);
    tablaPorFechas.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    
    
    

}
```

El error me sale exactamente así:
`error: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)` y despues esto:

[image: ERROR]

[image: ERROR]

EN LA LINEA 65 ESTA:

```
filter.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: Intenta poner los signos de interrogación **SIN** las comillas simples. es decir: `"SELECT * FROM ptjs_accounted WHERE fecha between ? and ?"`

Comment: Ya lo intente, me marca el mismo error :/

Comment: Normalmente las consultas parametrizadas se trabajan con `PreparedStatement`no tanto con `Statement`, siendo así, debes mandar la consulta usando `filter` que es el `PreparedStatement` en cuestión asi: `ResultSet rs = filter.executeQuery();`